# getting immediate text from an XML element with cheerio

Tags: node.js, cheerio

using `cheerio` to parse XML, consider

```
<foo>this<bar>that</bar></foo>
```

I want to get only "this" when I do `$('foo').text()` but I am getting "thisthat". How do I restrict the response to only the immediate text in the element *foo*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example in your question, you can get the text of the first child of foo:

```
$("foo")[0].children[0].data; //'this'
```

If instead you want all the immediate text inside of `foo`, you can iterate over its `children` and act on their `type`. Snippet:

```
function getImmediateText(str){
    let retStr = "";
    var $ = cheerio.load(str);  
    var children = $("foo")[0].children;

    children.forEach(function(child){
        //if type is text, add to return string
        if(child.type == "text")
            retStr += child.data;
    })
    return retStr;
}
```

If your text is `<foo>this<bar>that</bar>after</foo>`, this will return `thisafter`. You can easily change it to put spaces or line breaks between "this" and "after" if need be.